# Why do some anchor points have handles, and others have not?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, anchor-point

I'm new to Illustrator and I've come to a situation in which, strangely, some of my anchor points have handles, but others, instead of handles, they have a little ball that allow me to "smoothen" the edge.

Look:

[image]

How can I get rid of this little ball and get my handles back?

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of anchor points:

Corner points (with no handles) and Smooth points (with handles).

The handles control the curves and since corner points have no curves they have no handles. You can convert one kind of anchor point to the other in a number of ways:

1. Use the **Convert Anchor Point tool** (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
2. With the **Pen tool** (<kbd>P</kbd>) active, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the anchor point.
3. Select the anchor point with the **Direct Selection tool** (<kbd>A</kbd>) and use the *Convert* buttons in the Options Bar

[image]

The little "ball" you see on corner points is the [Live Corners widget](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html), which allows you to modify the corner and as the name suggests, only works on *corner* points.

Comment: What Cai said - plus if you want to sound fancy, they're called **Bezier Curve** handles.