# How to reach / create direction points if they are close to anchor point in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point, bezier-curve

I have sharp angle and wish to start to move control points

[image]

I dont see any direction points there. Either they are coincide with anchor point or they are very close to it.

Hot to start moving direction points in this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do some anchor points have handles, and others have not?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73729/why-do-some-anchor-points-have-handles-and-others-have-not)

Answer (score 1):

Step By Step Solution

Step 1:
Select the anchor point.
Take your cursor near that anchor point and you will see cursor with the rubberband.

[image]

Step 2: 
Click and drag a little.(while you can still see that icon) And you will start to see the direction points.

[image]

Also, If ever you stop seeing the rubberbands(direction handles). Go to view -> show edges.

[image]